# Function expressions are not supported in decorators, consider changing the function expression into and exported function

Tags: angular, typescript

I got this error: ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'ɵ0'
    'ɵ0' contains the error at app/app.module.ts(40,22)
      Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.

It says that is located in this piece of code:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoadingOverlayComponent,
    LoadingComponent,
    TrendsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: function tokenGetter() {
          return localStorage.getItem('token');
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RefreshJwtInterceptor, multi: true },],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I searched for this problem but I can't seem to find someone with the same kind of situation as mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to export inline function tokenGetter like this:

```js
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoadingOverlayComponent,
    LoadingComponent,
    TrendsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RefreshJwtInterceptor, multi: true },],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

More information with [Angular AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#no-arrow-functions)